# Deciphering this activator-akka-spray method

Tags: scala, spray

I have a background in Java but am now learning Scala to use with Spray. While looking through one of the sample programs, I encountered this method:

```
  /**
   * Marshals instances of ``Either[A, B]`` into appropriate HTTP responses by marshalling the values
   * in the left or right projections; and by selecting the appropriate HTTP status code for the
   * values in the left projection.
   *
   * @param ma marshaller for the left projection
   * @param mb marshaller for the right projection
   * @param esa the selector converting the left projection to HTTP status code
   * @tparam A the left projection
   * @tparam B the right projection
   * @return marshaller
   */
  implicit def errorSelectingEitherMarshaller[A, B](implicit ma: Marshaller[A],
      mb: Marshaller[B], esa: ErrorSelector[A]): Marshaller[Either[A, B]] =
      Marshaller[Either[A, B]] { (value, ctx) =>
      value match {
    case Left(a) =>
      val mc = new CollectingMarshallingContext()
      ma(a, mc)
      ctx.handleError(ErrorResponseException(esa(a), mc.entity))
    case Right(b) =>
      mb(b, ctx)
  }
}
```

What doesn't make sense to me is `(value, ctx)`. These appear to be parameters, but I don't know how anything could be passed in. Neither value or ctx are defined anywhere else as far as I can tell. How is this method supposed to work?

The sample can be found by typing activator-akka-spray in Typesafe Activator and looking in src/main/scala/api/DefaultJsonFormats.scala. (The file shown [here](https://github.com/eigengo/akka-patterns/blob/master/server/api/src/main/scala/org/eigengo/akkapatterns/api/marshalling.scala) contains the method, but the rest of the file is not identical) Here's the whole class:

```
package api

import spray.json._
import java.util.UUID
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import spray.httpx.marshalling.{MetaMarshallers, Marshaller, CollectingMarshallingContext}
import spray.http.StatusCode
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport

/**
 * Contains useful JSON formats: ``j.u.Date``, ``j.u.UUID`` and others; it is useful
 * when creating traits that contain the ``JsonReader`` and ``JsonWriter`` instances
 * for types that contain ``Date``s, ``UUID``s and such like.
 */
trait DefaultJsonFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport with MetaMarshallers {

  /**
   * Computes ``RootJsonFormat`` for type ``A`` if ``A`` is object
   */
  def jsonObjectFormat[A : ClassTag]: RootJsonFormat[A] = new RootJsonFormat[A] {
    val ct = implicitly[ClassTag[A]]
    def write(obj: A): JsValue = JsObject("value" -> JsString(ct.runtimeClass.getSimpleName))
    def read(json: JsValue): A = ct.runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  /**
   * Instance of the ``RootJsonFormat`` for the ``j.u.UUID``
   */
  implicit object UuidJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[UUID] {
    def write(x: UUID) = JsString(x.toString)
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsString(x) => UUID.fromString(x)
      case x           => deserializationError("Expected UUID as JsString, but got " + x)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Type alias for function that converts ``A`` to some ``StatusCode``
   * @tparam A the type of the input values
   */
  type ErrorSelector[A] = A => StatusCode

  /**
   * Marshals instances of ``Either[A, B]`` into appropriate HTTP responses by marshalling the values
   * in the left or right projections; and by selecting the appropriate HTTP status code for the
   * values in the left projection.
   *
   * @param ma marshaller for the left projection
   * @param mb marshaller for the right projection
   * @param esa the selector converting the left projection to HTTP status code
   * @tparam A the left projection
   * @tparam B the right projection
   * @return marshaller
   */
  implicit def errorSelectingEitherMarshaller[A, B](implicit ma: Marshaller[A], mb: Marshaller[B], esa: ErrorSelector[A]): Marshaller[Either[A, B]] =
    Marshaller[Either[A, B]] { (value, ctx) =>
      value match {
        case Left(a) =>
          val mc = new CollectingMarshallingContext()
          ma(a, mc)
          ctx.handleError(ErrorResponseException(esa(a), mc.entity))
        case Right(b) =>
          mb(b, ctx)
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Marshaller[Either[A, B]] { (value, ctx) => ... }` is short for `Marshaller.apply[Either[A, B]](...)`. The argument starting with `(value, ctx) =>` is an anonymous function that will be called by the infrastructure. See the definition of `Marshaller.apply` here: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/Marshaller.scala#L33

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marshaling is called implicitly by spray for the type it marshals. Spray will provide the value to be marshaled as well as the request context.